# django and sites framework chaining in relationships

Tags: django, django-models

A little question about one of the most useful django frameworks:

```
django.contrib.sites
```

Assuming I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    info = models.TextField()
    site = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
    objects = models.Manager()
    on_site = CurrentSiteManager()
```

and another model, that's linked to the given above:

```
class MyModelSupplement(models.Model):
    info = models.TextField()
    parent_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

Scheme specifies, that MyModelSupplement can't belong to sites, it's parent doesn't belong to.

having this structure I can access **MyModel** object on the given site simply by invoking

```
MyModel.on_site.all()
```

code. What's the best way to achieve the same on **MyModelSupplement** model?

I can think of a few ways to solve this:

1. putting the same **site** field in MyModelSupplement and defining the same CurrentSiteManager (won't that be a bit redundant?)
2. use `MyModelSupplement.objects.filter(parent_model__site__id = some_site_id)`
3. `MyModel.on_site.all().values_list('mymodelsupplement')`
4. Or even go to this variant:

```
my_models = MyModel.on_site.all()      
my_models_supplements = MyModelSupplements.objects.filter(parent_model__in=my_models).select_related()
```

is there a better way of accomplishing the mentioned task? The note is that I need to access both this models both together and separately, trying to retrieve instances respected to the given site?

Maybe there's a way to say something like: all SiteID values from `MyModel` should be in `MyModelSupplement`. If SiteID value was deleted from `MyModel` instance, it should be deleted from all `MyModelSupplements`, that are related to the the respected `MyModel` instance with ManyToMany relationship.

Is that achievable?

Comment: `mymodelsupplement.parent_model.site.all()` ?

Comment: this will retrive parent_model (MyModel in this case) instances, when I need MyModelSupplements instances. Not even sure your row will work, invoked from MyModelSupplement class (not it's instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem the following way:

this goes before everything happens:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

after that, we create a custom manager:

```
class OnSiteMyModelSupplementManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(OnSiteMyModelSupplementManager, self).get_query_set().filter(parent_model__sites=settings.SITE_ID)
```

and simply putting two more lines of code into MyModelSupplement class:

```
objects = models.Manager()
on_site = OnSiteMyModelSupplementManager()
```

and now I'm capable of retrieving MyModelSupplements, that belong only to the current web-site, as there parents do.